# Ajv validation always returns true

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema, ajv

I try to validate `JSON` data ragarding an existing JSON schema.

I tried

```
const filename = path.join(__dirname, 'google-wallet-object-schema.json') // from https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1
const schemas = require(filename)

const ajv = new Ajv({
    schemaId: 'auto',  
    additionalProperties: false,
    $data: true, 
    // unknownFormats: 'ignore',
    allErrors: true,
    validateSchema: true, 
    format: 'full', 
    //jsonPointers :true
    /* schemas: schemas.schemas */
})

ajv.addSchema(schemas.schemas).compile(schemas.resources);
const v = ajv.getSchema('#/flightobject/methods/insert')
const test = v({ dddd: '1' })
console.log(test)
console.log(ajv.errors)
```

where I expect `false` but the validation always returns `true` does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please include the schema in your question rather than an external link. Should the link vanish, your question would no longer be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Also, I cannot tell what the schema is from what you've provided.

Comment: @Relequestual https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 the schema collection is quite large. I do not think it will fit here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON document is not a JSON Schema.

According to https://developers.google.com/discovery

> A directory of supported APIs schemas ***based on JSON Schema***.
>
> A machine-readable "Discovery Document" for each of the supported
> APIs.

You'll have to either use the client libraries they supply, or write your own "Discovery Document" processor.

Comment: `validateSchema: true` does not throw an error. How could this be an invalid JSON Schema?

Comment: Because unknown keywords are ignored and none of the document root keywords are defined by JSON Schema (Apart from title and description, which are strings, so allowed).

Comment: The documentation says what you are looking at is a "Discovery Document" which is defined by Google, and I can tell by looking at the document root that it is NOT a JSON Schema.

Comment: What you are doing is the equivalent of passing an empty object as your schema, which adds no constraints, hence validation always passes.